# Sending Binary File in Express leads to ECONNABORTED

Tags: node.js, express, httprequest, form-data

I am currently working on some tests for a backend and I keep stumbeling that one test in particular sometimes runs through and sometimes it doesn't. The error happens in my guard to reject the request if some particular header is not present. So in my test the application looks similar to this

```
beforeEach(() => {
    app = express();
    const router = express.Router();
    router.post('/media/upload',      
      addSpies,
      PostMediaGuard(sinon.stub().resolves(true)),
      multer(getMulterOptions()).fields([{ name: 'File', maxCount: 1 }]),
      upload
    ); 

    app.use('/', router);
  });
```

Now add spies will just add spies to my req, res and next and the move on. The error happens in my PostMediaGuard. Here I will check for a header that is present and reject if it is not

**PostMediaGuard**

```
if(typeof(req.headers['x-some-header']) !== 'string')
      return res.status(400).end('No valid RealmId in Header. Please set X-RealmId');

    if(!await _userMayUploadMediaFile(
      req.headers['x-some-header'],
      req.headers.authorization as string,
      req.user
    ))
      return res.status(403).end(`Not allowed to upload media`);

next();
```

Now for my test I will just make a request to my app using supertest. and the request looks like this

**Test**

```
await request(app)      
        .post('/media/upload')      
        .attach('File', path.join(__dirname, '../../test/media/dummy.jpg'));
```

Now if I debug everything works fine and I will hit the line to set the status to 400 and end the request in the PostMediaGuard.  Sometimes after that the test gets asserted just fine and sometimes I'll get the ECONNABORTED with the following Stack

> stack:"Error: write ECONNABORTED
>       at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:150:25)
>       at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:141:3)
>       at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:770:11)
>       at Socket._write (net.js:782:8)
>       at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
>       at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:415:5)
>       at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:305:11)
>       at ClientRequest._writeRaw (_http_outgoing.js:295:17)
>       at ClientRequest._send (_http_outgoing.js:271:15)
>       at ClientRequest.end (_http_outgoing.js:732:10)
>       at Transform.onend (_stream_readable.js:691:10)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
>       at Transform.emit (events.js:210:5)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)"

Now I assume there is some streaming going on in the background because of the file that is being sent in the form-data of the request and I am trying to end the request before that is finished. However I have not started anything to process the data like creating a readstream or trying to store that in a database. (because the point of the guard is that I won't do that if the required header is not present). Practically all of the answers I found to that topic so far were due to some asynchrounous streaming methods beeing started and trying to end the request before that was completed. But as I have not started those at that point I don't know where I'm wrong

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now this seems to be an issue with supertest [(Issue on GitHub)](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/230)

However at least there is a workaround to make it work by setting the connection to keep alive in the header.

If you look at my example for the request in the question change it to something like this

```
await request(app)      
        .post('/media/upload')      
        .attach('File', path.join(__dirname, '../../test/media/dummy.jpg'))
        .set('Connection', 'keep-alive');
```

Now I still could not get my head around what exaclty happens with supertest. [This issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/747) states that on form-data request a double callback might be invoked so it could be related to that.

As of now I don't understand the root cause but I will update it here as soon as I find out. At least there is a workaround to make it work as of now.